# como funciona essa tag < base > do HTML?

Tags: html, html5, html-tags

***olá gostaria de saber como e que funciona essa tag < base > do HTML5 ?***

Comment: Essa tag não é do HTML5. Já era recomendação no HTML4.01.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a w3schools

> A tag  especifica a base URL / target para todas as URLs
>   relativos em um documento.
>   Pode haver no máximo um elemento  em um documento, e deve
>   estar dentro do elemento `<head>`.

Basicamente ela prefixa as importações de imagens, css, js, entre outros com uma url. exemplo:

```
<base href="/minhapasta/">
<img src="imgs/imagem.jpg">
```

Sem o base definido o navegador vai buscar a imagem de modo relativo a url onde o html que está rodando está. Digamos que esteja na raiz: `www.meusite.com/imgs/imagem.jpg`

Com o base ele o navegador vai buscar a imagem com o o prefixo definido ficando:
`www.meusite.com/minhapasta/imgs/imagem.jpg`

Referencia:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 1):

A tag  serve para definir a URL e o Target que serão padrão para toda a página.

Com isso todos os caminhos de imagens e links herdaram o caminho que foi definido no atributo href setado na tag base. Como por exemplo...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <base href="http://www.site.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="suaimagem.jpg" alt="Sua imagem">
    <a href="pagina.html">Link</a>
 </body>
```

Com isso todas as imagens já herdaram o caminho http://www.site.com/images/, bastando escrever apenas o nome da imagem no src, isso se torna interessante quando de repente você precisa alterar todas as suas imagens de uma pasta para outra, bastando apenas alterar o caminho no href da tag base, ao invés de alterar imagem por imagem em todo o seu site.

Mas esse caminho também será aplicado em todos os links do site, mas caso você não queira que os links herdem o href da tag base, basta escrever um caminho absoluto para o link ao invés de escrever caminhos relativos, como por exemplo...

```
<!-- Herdara o caminho definido na tag base -->
<a href="pagina.html">Link</a>
<!-- Não herdara o caminho definido na tag base -->
<a href="http://www.site.com/pagina.html">Link</a>
```

A tag base deve ser definida apenas uma vez na página, e dentro da tag , e principalmente antes de qualquer chamada de CSS ou JavaScript. Para que todos os CSSs e JavaScripts também peguem esse caminho já definido.

Outro atributo válido para a tag  é o target, que deve receber um dos seguintes valores...

- _blank
- _parent
- _self
- _top
- Nome de um frame

Com isso todos os seus links também herdaram esse valor para seus targets, não precisando definir link por link.

[Fonte](http://www.eversondaluz.com.br/tag-base-html)